# Will applying an ice pack to a laptop cause any issues?

Tags: laptop, temperature

Sometimes my laptop overheats crazily when I play a video game.

That's why sometimes I use an ice pack to help cool it down.

Is this dangerous? Like if the water from the pack melted or something?  Will it cause any issues if I just apply an ice pack directly to the laptop?

Comment: It is really just a question of water. If there is a chance that using the icepack could result in water getting into the laptop, then that will result in potentially permenent damage. If not, then you are helping draw heat out of the machine, which is a good thing.

Comment: So I put it underneath, like directly outside and underneath the laptop.  If it's hot enough that the ice pack slowly melts, can water from the ice pack get into the vents in the laptop and ruin it?

Comment: You are the only one who can know.  Either the icepack is wet when that happens, and so the answer is yes, or it is dry and the answer is no.  As per the answer below, condensation is a real possibility, depending on your climate.  Also, make sure you aren't blocking any vents.

Comment: how about putting the ice pack behind a table fan? The table fan draws air from behind and blows on to your laptop. So cooling is achieved by radiation rather than by conduction in your case. This cooling should be carefully controlled so that the cold air does not condense and settle down into your laptop. The other way to cool down is to get a notebook cooler. They come with pretty big fans

Comment: How about wrapping the icepak in a thin towel, and perhaps just leaving it on top of the chasis/keyboard area, rather than underneath?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably not a good idea. The condensation on the ice pack can get into your computer and destroy it. You may even end up cooling the laptop enough that condensation forms *inside* the chassis (though I don't know how likely this latter case actually is).

Answer (score 0):

Dont do this if you have a macbook pro. I just did this and then all of a sudden the monitor stopped coming on. The hard drive seems to be churning but there is no image. I was just watching a video on Youtube (computer gets really hot when video playback is taking place) And then the monitor flicked a couple of times and then it was OVER. Now I have to go to that God forsaken Apple store or Mac TLC.

Answer (score 0):

I do this all the time with my Surface Pro 7 and MacBook Pro (mid 2015, 15 inch), and I never had a problem before. It's probably because the environment they are in has low humidity, so there wouldn't be condensation. The ice pack method seems to work quite well, with the fan on the surface pro turning off because it cooled down significantly. Just make sure that the environment that the laptop is in isn't too humid.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I put two sealed ice packs underneath my cooling tray but had them wrapped in a thin cloth to stop condensation. it worked to reduce heat by cooling the air the fans were blowing on the laptop. it didn't reduce it by a crazy amount but it did help, I would guess it reduced it by 5 to 10*c

Comment: Hello, do you think "worked for me" is a good answer in this case where e.g. a process called melting combined with a hole in the back could be detrimental to the device?